# How to see real rendering elements in karma test?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have a new angular14 project.But after I finished writing the unit test, I only saw a bunch of successful text information, and did not see HTML elements. How do I see HTML elements?

Answer (score 0):

After run "ng test" and Karma window opened in browser, you can see an preview by clicking in "DEBUG" button.

With "DEBUG" tab opened, components from tests are rendered on screen.

Example:

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-karma-testing?file=app%2Fpersist%2Fdisplay-name.directive.spec.ts

In this example, is possible see the rendered HTML:

[image]

Comment: A better answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72788359/2946008

Comment: Hmmm... I forgot that detail.